# Possessive for Name Ending in Apostrophe

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

One of my colleagues has a name that ends in an apostrophe, namely Faee'. Recently when sending an email I realized I wasn't sure how to refer to something that belongs to them using the typical " 's " possessive structure and ended up rewriting my sentence to avoid this. My question is whether I am safe to just use " 's " in the future or if I should be doing something different.

Comment: I suspect there is no satisfactory answer.  Suppose you have a restaurant owned by two brothers called Jones.  So they call it JONES'.  An advertisement urging you to 'Try Jones''(?) or Jones''s'(?) Will always look weird.  So put it differently or leave out the apostrophe from the name.  If the name itself ends in an apostrophe, then either say 'The car belonging tonJones' or just write Jones' car and stop worrying.

Comment: What is the name that ends with apostrophe? What about a name that ends with a question mark? when the sentence is not a question?

Comment: I too am curious about this name.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just an acute accent that gets faked in ASCII by an apostrophe? If so, just use a unicode letter for the accented vowel.

Comment: I updated the question to include the name, and I'm fairly certain it is not a case of ASCII being unable to cope as in their own writing the apostrophe appears (i.e. on their webpage).

Comment: You're the editor, be bold and consistent. If you have no style sheet that addresses this unusual and pressing your issue, set your style for it. Stick to it. When they drag you away questioning your radical decision, keep repeating *I had to*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Well put.

Comment: Rewording to use "of" (or "by" or similar) seems the simplest answer. This must be a problem with a lot of languages that use a symbol similar to an apostrophe for a letter or mark at the end of words: Arabic as well as some Slavic languages and maybe some Oceanic languages (I'm not sure if it's ever word-final in Hawaiian).